# Can I be legally compelled, in the U.S., to return/destroy old work emails that are on my own laptop?

Tags: ownership, data-ownership, email

I used to work remotely and had my own hardware, etc. The company used Microsoft exchange (or similar) to run their email, store it on servers, etc. They killed my email account when I left but all my emails still remain on my laptop. Do they have a right to compel me to destroy the emails on my computer? Do I have a legal right to keep them?

Answer (score -2):

> Do they have a right to compel me to destroy the emails on my computer?

They have the right to apply for a court order to get you destroy the emails. But this would hardly ever be granted unless the emails contain data affecting national security (in which case you won't legally have it on your own hardware in the first place).

> Do I have a legal right to keep them?

You do, provided that a court has not said otherwise. You cannot, however, use them for anything but your own reminiscing of the time you worked for the company, or as evidence should you decide to sue them (or be sued by them).

You also may become liable should the emails leak from your hardware (e.g. stolen by a hacker, or accidentally uploaded to a cloud storage and made available to others).

Comment: National Security? It is likely that the OP also pre-agreed to not take company trade secrets with him.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Yes there would have been an NDA. But keeping for yourself and disclosing are different things. You can't "not to take" anyway as you cannot erase your own memory.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Well, that is an interesting topic. I never signed or agreed to anything before working as an "independent contractor" for the company

Comment: @Greendrake I appreciate the answer...is there legal precedent or something you can cite that would support this position?

Comment: @Sizzle None off the top of my head. This answer just applies my understanding of how law operates. I often post these out of curiosity if they get challenged/proved wrong.

Comment: It was phrased very authoritatively for something posted "out of curiosity" to see if it might be "proved wrong".

Comment: @GeorgeWhite That's just style. No intention to assume authority. Is that the mere reason for downvote, or do you have anything substantial to prove the answer wrong?

Comment: I did downvote - an answer generated semi-randomly to amuse the answerer should be reflected by a low score.

Comment: Funny to see that the only way people can challenge the correctness of this answer so far is to downvote it. So pathetic.

Comment: @Greendrake That's not how correctness works.  You claim to have it, ergo you must prove it.  Not us.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Noone owes anything to anyone here. Neither I must prove the correctness, nor anyone must to disprove it. I am just expressing amazement at people being eager to downvote just because the answerer dares to answer out of his expertise only without giving any prooflinks — even if they don't have anything to say against the correctness of the answer.